# Cannot get node.js to connect to pubnub from corporate network

Tags: node.js, proxy, pubnub

I cannot get the pubnub node.js starter program here (https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/master/node.js) to work.

I keep getting

> FAILED! RETRY PUBLISH! { message: 'timeout' }

so it looks like some kind of network issue.  I am behind corporate proxy and have set the http proxy env variables

I tried the ([javascript browser sdk](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk)) and it works.

Comment: The code works from home, so it's the corporate network that is blocking the connection to pubnub.  How do I find out what protocol the node.js SDK uses and what ports it may be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## PubNub Node and Proxies

You need to pass in the Proxy info in the configuration, will look similar to the code below.

```
pubNubClient = require('pubnub')({
  ssl          : true,
  publish_key  : "YOUR_PUBLISH_KEY",
  subscribe_key: "YOUR_SUBSCRIBE_KEY",
  proxy: {
     hostname: "http://google.com",
     port: "1234"
  }
});
```